# Format of marks in viminfo

Tags: vim

I'm trying to find information on how file marks are stored in the [`'viminfo'`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27viminfo%27) file. For example, here is an entry I have:

```
'0  3  11  ~/.vim/hello
|4,48,3,11,1592944829,"~/.vim/hello"
```

The only obvious things from the above seem to be the filepath the mark is saved, `~/.vim/hello` and the timestamp it was created `1592944829`. What are the other items, and why are some of the items listed multiple times (3, 11, filename).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are reading the wrong block.

In the `viminfo` file, search for the lines beginning with `>`, they are mark histories.

And there is usually comment in the file.

For example:

```
# History of marks within files (newest to oldest):

> /tmp/test/whatevertestfile.txt
    *   1592998167  0
    "   4   0
    ^   1   0
    .   1   0
    +   1   0
    a   4   0
    b   9   0
```

### update

Oh, I just noticed you mentioned file marks in the question. Then you are looking at the right block.

The positions in the two lines are always the same because the `write_one_filemark()` function reads the same values for the two lines.

- The first `4` is an index in the viminfo file, it indicates the mark type.
- The `48` is the ascii code of the numbered mark `0` .
- Then come the position + ts + filename

If you want to know more detailed, why it is so defined and so on, you can read the related part of this file
https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/master/src/viminfo.c